# Qt. getting item position of item on view problems

Tags: qt, view, graphics, printing, scene

well I'm having a very hard time figuring out how am I going to do this:

I have a tablemodel. I want to print some fields of that model that contain text. I need a widget to be able to position each field on the "paper" arbitrary. Like making a collage with the text data. I want the data of each field to printed on the position that was selected through the widget.

To do this I thought on the Graphics/View framework, creating a scene containing graphics items that are reference to the fields and the relative position I want them on the paper, example: "name" near up-left corner, "address" in the center of the view, etc

Until now, I have created a view but the main problem is I don't know how to get a particular item position after I added it to the scene. I need to know the "address item" position so that I draw the "address field" text on the to-be-printed paper in the same relative position.

Can anyone guide me on how to do this? Please ask for clarification if you can't understand what my problem is? It has been difficult to me to explain it.

Comment: I am a bit confused by the 'paper' part. Does this mean that you want to be able to print the collage as you call it?

Comment: I gave up this way of doing what I commented above and instead I made a widget with a textEditor that has the image in the background, through codes in the written text and letting empty all unwanted text appearing on the image (over the textEditor) I was able to get an editable position input lineedit form that is filled programatically using the data of a model... Thanks for the answer anyway